# Why isnt there a "new custom http rule" option in EC2 security groups

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-ec2, port

I am connecting to my http server using http ://XXXX:15672
In the security group I want to declare a new custom http rule, in the inbound tab, supplying source and target port, but there is no option to do it.
http rule automatically assigns it to 80.
custom tcp rule allows adding port.

1. Why can't I add a port to an http rule?
2. Can I use "TCP + PORT"  custom rule for http reaquests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An `HTTP Rule` is actually simply syntactic sugar for `TCP Rule for port 80`. For your purposes, you should definitely use Custom TCP Rule:

[image: tcp rule]